# How to pick up the secondary classification of the current classification

Tags: postgresql

There are two tables：stock_move, stock_location

stock_move:

```
 id | loc_id | loc_name | loc_dest_id | loc_dest_name
--- |---     |---       |---          |---
1   | 13     | wh/B     | 27          | wh/A/A1
2   | 13     | wh/B     | 38          | wh/A/A1/001
3   | 25     | wh/A     | 13          | wh/B
4   | 45     | wh/A/A3  | 17          | wh/B/B1
```

stock_location:

```
 id | name        | parent_id | code 
--- |---          |---        |---        
13  | wh/B        | 7         | 
7   | wh          |           | stock  
27  | wh/A/A1     | 25        | 
38  | wh/A/A1/001 | 27        |       
45  | wh/A/A3     | 25        | 
17  | wh/B/B1     | 13        | 
25  | wh/A        | 7         |
```

How to generate table tem_table:

```
 id | loc_id | loc_name | loc_dest_id | loc_dest_name | loc_group_id | loc_dest_group_id
--- |---     |---       |---          |---            |---           |---
1   | 13     | wh/B     | 27          | wh/A/A1       |13            |25
2   | 13     | wh/B     | 38          | wh/A/A1/001   |13            |25
3   | 25     | wh/A     | 13          | wh/B          |25            |13
4   | 45     | wh/A/A3  | 17          | wh/B/B1       |25            |13
```

Comment: ‘wh' is a primary classification, 'wh/A' and 'wh/B' are secondary classifications

Comment: I believe you have to explain your expected output. There is too much space for interpretation on how it could be achieved.

Comment: @S-Man

I want to get the expected result with "with tem_table as(select .. from 'xxoo')".
Where loc_group_id is the secondary classification ID corresponding to loc_id, and loc_dest_group_id is the secondary classification ID of loc_dest_id.
The first classification is 'wh'.

Comment: I have another idea to add a column called "secondary classification" (sec_root) to the table stock_location, now I need a function 'get_sec_root',
"""select id, name, parent_id, code, get_sec_root() as sec_root from stock_location""";
How to write this function?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Changsha Joan

```
WITH RECURSIVE x ( id  , location_id , path) AS
( SELECT id , location_id ,array[id]
    FROM stock_location
   WHERE location_id is null
   UNION ALL
  SELECT b.id , b.location_id, x.path || b.id
    FROM x, stock_location b
   WHERE x.id = b.location_id
),
tem as (SELECT id  , location_id , path[2]
  FROM x
 order by id)
select * from tem;
```